# Left join with union [MYSQL]

Tags: mysql, left-join, union

I have two queries. Both works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM newser t1 LEFT JOIN users t2 ON t1.userid = t2.usid WHERE t1.univer = '210310213053' LIMIT 1
```

second query:

```
SELECT * FROM newser ORDER by RAND() LIMIT 8
```

Union this:

```
SELECT * FROM newser WHERE univer = '210310213053' LIMIT 1) UNION (SELECT * FROM newser ORDER by RAND() LIMIT 8)
```

Works ok but I would like to add left join:

```
(SELECT * FROM newser t1 LEFT JOIN users t2 ON t1.userid = t2.usid WHERE t1.univer = '210310213053' LIMIT 1) UNION (SELECT * FROM newser ORDER by RAND() LIMIT 8)
```

Dosent work...
#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Can you please help me to do it properly?

Comment: The message is pretty clear. What don't you understand about it?

Comment: Do what properly? Wrong code doesn't tell us what you wish it did. PS In code questions give a (cut & paste & runnable) [mre].

Answer (score 0):

in union queries try not to use `SELECT *`, type the columns that you want to select, because maybe in future you would add new columns to on of these tables so the query will crash

Answer (score 0):

All the columns in a union must match.

You are selecting all columns from newser and users and trying to combine it with only columns from newser.

You will need to add placeholders ie `union (select *, null, null, null...`

with nulls to represent the columns from users; alternatively specify explicitly which columns you require.